# No module named MySQLdb error

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

When I use the python console and use

```
import MySQLdb
```

no errors occur.
When i use a bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
```

I get the following errors

```
 File "./jaccard.py", line 2, in <module>
 import MySQLdb
 ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

printing `sys.path`

```
 import sys; print(sys.path)
```

outputs

```
'/Users/kinetechsolutions/Dropbox/Code', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'
```

and

```
MySQLdb.__file__
```

crashes the commandline of python

Comment: What does `echo $PYTHONPATH` say on the command line? What does it print, if you place this line into your shell script? Are you using "environment" tools like `pyenv`?

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH gives blank line. I mean no path set. And i am not using pyenv.

Comment: Also useful: `import sys; print(sys.path)` - and in your console you can do `MySQLdb.__file__` to find out where it lives.

Comment: One thing more when i run it like this python jaccard.py every thing seems fine

Comment: What does `type python` return ?

Comment: type python :                                                                                         python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: You realize that `/Library/Frame..../bin/python` is not the same as `#!/usr/bin/python` right..?  Try `#!/usr/bin/env python` (I'm assuming that works on a mac too...)